# The php code com/?bid= shows over 200 broken INTERNAL links

Tags: php

Our index.php goo.gl/JK9RiF has about 30 internal (text and image links) placed to navigate users to our other pages.

With a very good tool online goo.gl/QtrldI I have run a Find Broken Links and Redirects checker to see that addition to 30 internal links, I interestingly see that there are about 200 other "internal links showing" up on the list with an HTTP OK 200 Status. Perhaps I don't know what this simple error is called in php language ?

but all the links show the same extension from our main page http://domainname.com/?bid=

Somewhere in index.php the page is telling search engines, that there are 200 more existing links with the found status, when they don't hand placed or "physically exist".

Any help on how can I fix the simple error? Thks

**I only see these code working with the database, in index.php.**

```
<TABLE border=0 class=normalyazi>
            <TR>
              <TD width=176 height=25 align=center vAlign=top class=tdform1><SELECT   
name=ilce class=searchuzun id=select2>
                  <option value=0 selected>Select Location</option>
                  <option value=1>Belek </option>
                  <option value=2>Side </option>
                  <option value=3>Alanya</option>
                  <option value=4>Antalya</option>
                  <option value=6>Kemer</option>
                  <option value=7>Kas</option>
                  <option value=8>Kalkan</option>
                  <option value=9>Fethiye</option>
              </SELECT></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD height=25 align=center class=tdform1><SELECT class=searchuzun 
id=eturu onchange=Disable() name=eturu>
                  <option value=0 selected>Select Type</option>
                  <option value=1>Apartment</option>
                  <option value=2>Villa </option>
                  <option value=3>Hotel</option>
                  <option value=4>Land</option>
              </SELECT></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD height=25 align=center class=tdform1><input class=searchuzun     
name=minprice value= Min Price (euro) onClick=this.value=''/></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD height=25 align=center class=tdform1><input class=searchuzun 
name=maxprice value= Max Price (euro) onClick=this.value=''/></TD>
            </TR>
            <tr>
              <TD align=center class=tdform1><INPUT class=but1 id=search type=submit 
value=Search name=search></TD>
            </tr>
          </TABLE>
          <br>
      </FORM></TD>
    </TR>
</table></td>
```

**and a bit lower is this**

```
<?

//random emlak kayitlari

$sql = "SELECT

emlakkayit.id,

emlakkayit.ilce,

emlakkayit.fiyat,

emlakkayit.aciklama,

emlakkayit.resim1,

emlakkayit.eturu,

bolge.bolge,

emlak_turu.tur

FROM

emlakkayit 

LEFT JOIN emlak_turu    ON emlakkayit.eturu=emlak_turu.id 

LEFT JOIN bolge         ON emlakkayit.ilce=bolge.id 

WHERE 

emlakkayit.edurum!='3' AND emlakkayit.resim1!='' 

GROUP BY emlakkayit.id 

ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,2" ;    

$DB->sorgula($sql);

while($randomemlak = $DB->objegetir($DB->sorgu_id))

{   

?>
    <tr>
      <td valign=top><table width="98%" border=0>
          <tr>
            <td height="12" colspan=3 class="l4"><strong>
              <?=$randomemlak->bolge?>
              </strong> -
              <?=$randomemlak->tur?>
            </a></td>
          </tr>
          <TR>
            <TD width=5 vAlign=bottom><DIV align=justify></DIV></TD>
            <TD width=107 vAlign=bottom><?  
if(is_file("resimler/".$randomemlak->resim1)){ ?>
      <img src="resimler/<?=$randomemlak->resim1?>" alt=Featured Property in     
Antalya width=95 height=70 vspace=3 align=top>
                <? } else { ?>
                <? } ?>
                <br>
                <br></TD>
            <TD width=97 vAlign=top class=kalinsiyah11Copy><p>&euro;
                    <?=number_format($randomemlak->fiyat);?>
                    <br>
                    <span class=alticizgililink3>
                    <? if($randomemlak->eturu=="4") $mdl="detail_land"; else     
$mdl="detail"; ?>
                    <a href=<?=$mdl?>.php?KKId=<?=$randomemlak->id?>&
Ino=<?=$randomemlak->ilce?> class=alticizgililink3>
                    <?=substr($randomemlak->aciklama,0,60)?>
                </a>...</span></p></TD>
</TR>
</table></td>
</tr>
<? } 

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);

//random emlak son

?>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your `index.php` here. Not many of us are willing to visit a 3rd party shortened URL

Comment: But if your `index.php` accepts a parameter into `$_GET` and doesn't protect it in any way (if it isn't meant to be public), people and search engines will find it. [Sometimes with serious consequences](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/11/internet-troll-who-exploited-att-security-flaw-faces-5-years-in-jail/)

Comment: On the other hand, if your index.php doesn't even use a `?bid=` parameter, you can probably disregard whatever that tool reported to you as a false positive because the index.php will be a 200 even when unneeded parameters are sent to it.

Comment: the index.php uses a bid parameter, i added the code above but not sure where to fix. you are right in google wmt there are duplicate title tag errors for urls like .php?bid=9&page=333 and i am assuming it is because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you misread the response from this tool, or maybe you fixed it by now?

Anyways when running the same tool over your main page (www.turkish-property-world.com) it shows about 20 internal links (about.php, contact.php, etc.) which it has problems with, because it received a `403` (permission denied). Probably because the server is somehow automatically blocking the crawl, since those same links work fine when visiting them directly.

The first one just shows a `200 OK` message, which only means that the response was alright / no error.

Also with the SEO optimization tool from the same page, it shows a total of 39 internal links (and 2 external ones), which seems to be pretty ok. (Also the same links giving 403 before, resolve fine here.

The only other thing I could imagine, is that it took some time for the prior changes (.htaccess as well as php redirects) from your last question to take place - but it seems somehow unlikely since that tool is meant to crawl your page live :-)